# Ejecutar función al pulsar botón de navegador Atras

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría poder deshabilitar la funcionalidad del botón atrás y ejecutar una función. He estado leyendo pero no encuentro nada al respecto.
Estoy usando javascript.

Una de las cosas que he intentado es esto:

```
if (history.go(-1))
{
acciones a ejecutar
}
```

Pero directamente va atrás. hay poca información al respecto y la que hay se refiere a la modificación del history.

Mi idea es que al pulsar en el botón del navegador  de atrás, ejecute una función.

Comment: Hola Lorenzo, te recomiendo especificar el lenguaje y/o tecnología que estás usando.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado o buscado? Google muestra [bastantes resultados](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=K10eW5CbH8HmswHB96TQAg&q=navegador+detectar+pulsar+atr%C3%A1s&oq=navegador+detectar+pulsar+atr%C3%A1s&gs_l=psy-ab.3...703.703.0.1115.2.1.0.0.0.0.130.130.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0.0...0.abv24rlZE30)

Answer (score 1):

Se puede captar un evento cuando va hacia atras en el botón de navegación usando este evento:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
 console.log("hola");
};
```

Este evento caza TODO evento que modifique la navegación. Deberias investigar en el evento (variable e) para distinguir los diferentes tipos de movimientos de navegación.

Respecto a cancelar el evento, no es posible cancelar un evento de atras por el navegador, los eventos unload y onbeforeload son eventos no cancelables.

Para mas información te recomiendo mirar la documentación de window de MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window

Answer (score 1):

Para deshabilitar el botón "atrás" deberás utilizar este código, por ejemplo:

```
function noatras(){
window.location.hash="no-back-button";
window.location.hash="Again-No-back-button"
window.onhashchange=function(){
                    window.location.hash="no-back-button";
                    }
}
```

Luego tenemos que cargar la función desde el `<body>`

```
<body  onload="noatras();">
```

Answer (score -3):

2 formas de ir Atrás en el navegador.

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

ó

```
window.history.back();
```

Comment: No ha preguntado como ir, si no como evitarlo.